# convert ereg_replace to preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, posix-ere

i have the following ereg_replace statement:

```
ereg_replace ( ".*alternative0=\"[^\"]*\"[ ]{0,10}>", "", $v );
```

since `ereg_replace` is deprecated I would like to upgrade it to `preg_replace` and I also want to upgrade my code so only the first occurrence will be replaced.

```
preg_replace ("/.*alternative0=\".*?\".*>/", "", $v,1 );
```

but it seems to work partially.

the major problem is that when I have whitespace between the `"` and `>` my preg does not work

here are some example strings i want to to change:

```
<tag type="head" alternative0="not head">{!head!}</tag>
<tag type="tail" alternative0="tail>{!not tail!}</tag>
```

but it also may be:

```
<tag type="head" alternative0="not head">{!
xxxx   !}</tag>
```

or even:

```
<tag type="header" alternative0="not head "    > {!  blah bla !}</tag>
```

Comment: Tip: First convert. Ensure it works as before. Then ask a second question about your (new) regex problem with the count of matching.

Comment: Maybe provide some example strings that you want to match your pattern, since you're converting and slightly changing the behavior of your pattern from `"[^\"]*"[ ]{0,10}` to `".*?".*`

Comment: maybe someone can explain to me what is the preg equivalent to "[ ]{0,10}" since that seems to be the only issue in my pattern.


iv'e edieted the post and added some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a more efficient pattern with this:

```
preg_replace ('/.*alternative0="[^"]++"[^>]*+>/', "", $v, 1);
```

You can't use something like: `.*>` because the dot match all characters and the quantifier * is greedy thus the `.*` match the final > too and the `>` from the pattern is never matched or not matched at the good offset.

Comment: thank you Casimir, your pattern does not seem to work correctly since it ignores white spaces

Comment: Casimir, thanks a lot iv'e made a little modification that seems to work '/.*alternative0="[^"]*+"[^>]*+>/'

Comment: @sd1sd1: Sorry I haven't seen your previous comment! Indeed the pattern don't match a void attribute.